# Connection access Database through Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp

I'm Newbie.is it possible the connect Hibernate with access Database as i came cross few posts in which are suggesting to connect it Mysql , Microsoft SQLSever , oracle

Comment: please try to specify more exactly what you want and show us what you already did

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you have to search for a user implemented access-hibernate-dialect (I think http://www.hxtt.com/hibernate.html could be a source)

Answer (score -1):

I think NO. I dont see any hibernate dialect for MS Access